# Array of Hashes with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

ActiveRecord (Rails 4.0) supports PostgreSQL Hstore and Array datatypes, so an Array of Hashes is theoretically possible, but my implementation throws:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal:
```

The error is obvious (double quote conflict):

```
"{"null"=>"false","name"=>"schema_id","type"=>"integer","null"=>"false","name"=>"title","type"=>"text"}"

: INSERT INTO "entities" ("attribute_hash", "schema_id", "title") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

The solution is not obvious to me, how can I implement this?

My schema:

```
create_table :schemas do |t|
  t.text    :title
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :entities do |t|
  t.integer :schema_id,       null: false
  t.text    :title,           null: false
  t.hstore  :attribute_hash, array: true
end
```

My seed:

```
@schema_id = Schema.create!(title: 'accreu')
Entity.create!(
  schema_id: @schema_id.id, title: 'entities',
  attribute_hash: [
    {null: "false", name: :schema_id, type: :integer},
    {null: "false", name: :title, type: :text}
   ]
)
```

Comment: You're trying to define a dynamic table schema using an array of hstore?

Comment: @CraigRinger for my application this is the ideal schema at this time. You are welcome to share your alternatives, but my question is valid and I'm looking for constructive responses.

Comment: @muistooshort. The goal is an array of hstores, correct.

Comment: Personally I strongly suspect that a side-table with a foreign key relationship will be preferable to using an array, so each child record has a single `hstore` field plus the parent ID and any useful fixed fields. That way you'll be working with tested and supported features. Otherwise I won't be too surprised if you land up doing some ActiveRecord bugfixing - an array of `hstore` is weird enough that it might not be tested and supported at this time.

Comment: I suspect that a `json` column would be less painful.

Comment: I'll keep this question open as it still represents a 'bug' in Rails, but the alternatives of adding an entity or json datatype swap are both viable. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in Rails that was fixed in commit [7c32db1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7c32db1), which is present in versions 4.1.0.rc1 and later.