# Rails: parse and save array to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I try to parse text from text area for making array and save him to DB (postgresql)
and getting next error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: malformed array literal: "{{}}" : UPDATE "categories" SET "advanced_params" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "categories"."id" = 8
```

**_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= f.text_area :advanced_params %>
```

**category.rb**:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :parse_category_params

protected
    def parse_category_params
        self.advanced_params = advanced_params.split("/, /")
    end
end
```

**schema.rb**:

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "advanced_params",     array: true
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Text area data for example: *1234, check, sometext*

### UPD:

Log output:

```
SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "categories" SET "advanced_params" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "categories"."id" = 8  [["advanced_params", "{{}}"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-12 22:28:59.917767"]]
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: malformed array literal: "{{}}"
```

Comment: Using `params` for a field name is asking for trouble.  The name `params` is already used for the GET or POST parameters hash.

Comment: Ok, i change field name to `advanced_params`, but it's not helping

Comment: Might be bug in Rails, check your version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596826/array-of-hashes-with-activerecord